# CSS Not Selector: Select All Except Inside of Element

Tags: css

I have the class "item" appearing throughout the page. The styling is the same throughout the page. However, I don't want the styling to be applied when it appears in an element with the class "group". I'd really like to use the :not pseudo selector so I don't have to create another style for this special case.

CSS

```
.item, .group div:not(.item){
    color:red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="item">I have style!</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="item">No style for me, thanks!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a perfect solution, but you could target the `.group` div and say something like:

```
div:not(.group) .item {
    color: red;
}
```

Here's a fiddle to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/jqxgetsj/

The only constraint is that you have to have direct parent selectors or something rather targeted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) value and do it this way:

```css
.item {
    color:red;
}
.group div.item {
    color:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">I have style!</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="item">No style for me, thanks!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like a decent solution, but not supported in IE. I'd second this method, but add a defined color fallback for IE. Or better yet, just replace initial with the color intended for items not in `.group`s.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no parent selector in CSS, so you can't go inside out. Theres a child selector though, which can be used great in your example:

```css
body > .item {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">I have style!</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="item">No style for me, thanks!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought of this as well. However I have that item throughout the dom on my site (dynamically applied).